# How to map address changes from an account to it's child contacts

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I have the following question, because I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation.
I am using Dynamics CRM 4.0.

My problem is the following, and I might be missing something here, but:
If I add an account "X" with address: Street 123 and I add a child contact "Y" belonging to that account.

If I change the address of the account "X", should it automatically change the address of the belonging account "Y"?

I thought these fields (the address fields) are inherited? How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

There is only a one-time mapping defined, which maps this fields when you create a contact from a account record.

After you have created the contact, it is not updated on address changes. If you have this requirement, you should implement a plugin which transfers the required data from the account to all of its contacts.

I'm not aware of any free plugin, but it is a rather simple one to implement.

You can't solve this with a workflow, because there is no activity which could be used to iterate over the contacts of the account. For this task you would have to implement a custom workflow activity, which is at least the same amount of work as to develop the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a standard plug-in already? Else I can make a workflow for that purpose, but I wonder if there is already  standard solution?

Comment: My bad then. I thought the address fields were inherited. I will keep on looking for a solution. Thank you for the help. I do appreciate it.